# Compare too variable script shell

Tags: linux, image, docker, shell, tags

```
echo "The tag in the last image heberged on the registry:"
var="docker images "localhost:5000/*" --format='{{.Tag}}' | head -1"

if [ "$var" == '2' ]
then
echo "its equal"
else
echo "its not equal"

eval "$var"
```

with ./script.sh i have my tag which is 2 but the function if doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. It seems like your questions lacks a meaningful description. Please include such information as what you are trying to achieve, what are the actual and expected results.

Comment: `$var` is equal to `docker image ...`, not `2`. See the duplicate for how to run a command and assign the output to a variable.